# array of LocalBusinessJsonLd Schema using next-seo

Tags: reactjs, next.js, schema.org, json-ld

Hi I am trying to add multiple localbusiness schema in my next js application,
I am using next-seo package for this

```
import { LocalBusinessJsonLd } from 'next-seo'

{locations.map((location) => (
    <LocalBusinessJsonLd 
      type="Store"
      name={location.node.name}
      description={location.node.description}
      telephone={location.node.phone}
      address={{
        streetAddress: `${location.node.street}`,
        addressLocality: `${location.node.city}`,
        postalCode: `${location.node.postalCode}`,
        addressCountry: `${location.node.countryIso}`,
      }}
    />
))}
```

But when I did inspect its showing only last location in the schema not array of schema

Answer (score 0):

This part of the documentation might help you: [next-seo - Handling multiple instances](https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo#handling-multiple-instances)

> If your page requires multiple instances of a given JSON-LD component, you can specify unique keyOverride properties, and next-seo will handle the rest.
> This comes in handy for blog rolls, search results, and overview pages.
> Please fully research when you should and shouldn't add multiple instances of JSON-LD.

```
<ExampleJsonLd keyOverride="my-new-key" />
```